# The eigenvalues of the product of a positive definite and a symmetric matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A fellow student posed the following question and I'd like to stop thinking about it so I can get back to work on my own research!

---

Suppose that $A>0$, i.e. $A$ is a real symmetric positive definite matrix, and $B$ is a real symmetric nonsingular matrix.

What can we say about the eigenvalues of $AB$?  For instance, suppose $B$ has $n$ positive and $m$ negative eigenvalues.  Will $AB$ have the same number of positive and negative eigenvalues?

Obviously if $B$ is either positive or negative definite, the result is straightforward, i.e. we have the `matrix sign rules'

$$
(+)\cdot (+)=(+)\qquad\text{and}\qquad (+)\cdot(-)=(-)
$$ Whereby we mean `a positive definite times a positive definite has positive eigenvalues' and 'a positive definite times a negative definite has negative eigenvalues'.

Playing around with matrix decompositions such as polar, spectral, etc, and identities such as $\{\lambda(AB)\}=\{\lambda(\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A})\}$ (here $\lambda(\cdot)$ meaning `eigenvalues of') doesn't seem to lead to a quick result.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Obviously if B is either positive or negative definite..." Obviously? $A B$ is not even symmetric in general. I think you need to place more conditions.

Comment: @leonbloy What I said is true...see e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326944/evaluating-eigenvalues-of-a-product-of-two-positive-definite-matrices?rq=1) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113842/product-of-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices-is-positive-definite).  The _eigenvalues_ of the product will be positive (or negative), even if the product is not symmetric.  This follows since $\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A}$ is symmetric and $\lambda(AB)=\lambda(\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A})$

Comment: Ah, it's ok then. But I doubt there is a simple rule, unless A and B have a common eigenvectors base.

Comment: I doubt you can say much or anything about the eigenvalues of $AB$, since you know so little about $B$.  Note that $AB$ does not even need to be symmetric.  I think trying all those matrix decompositions is a waste of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Yes, the number of positive or negative eigenvalues in $AB$ and $B$ are the same. The spectrum of $AB$ is identical to the spectrum of $\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A}$ and by [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), $\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A}$ and $B$ have the same number of positive/negative/zero eigenvalues.

Comment: Aha, Sylvester's law of inertia...that was the missing piece. Thanks!