# Eigenvalues of positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A, B$ be positive definite matrices. What can be said about the maximum eigenvalue of $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you provide some context for your question? What motivates it? Did you get it out of a textbook? What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

What can be said: as Omnomnomnom mentioned, it is less than or equal the product of the largest eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$. Other than that, not a lot can be said.

For instance, you could have 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Here $\lambda_1(A)=2$, $\lambda_2(B)=3$, $\lambda_1(AB)=3$.

But if
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ B=\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},
$$
now $\lambda_1(A)=2$, $\lambda_2(B)=3$, $\lambda_1(AB)=6$.

Or if 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1/10\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ B=\begin{bmatrix}1/10&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix},
$$
now $\lambda_1(A)=2$, $\lambda_2(B)=3$, $\lambda_1(AB)=0.3$. Pushing this idea one can make $\lambda_1(AB)$ as close to $0$ as desired, without changing $\lambda_1(A)$ nor $\lambda_1(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\|A\|$ denote the spectral norm of $A$ (which gives the largest eigenvalue for positive definite matrices).  We have
$$
\|B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}\| \leq
\|B^{1/2}\| \cdot \|A\| \cdot \|B^{1/2}\| = \|A\|\|B\|
$$
that is, it is at most the product of the largest eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: See also Bhatia's matrix analysis for some more elaborate inequalities

Comment: Are you sure that doesn't hold with equality? This post seems to suggest that the eigenvalues of $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ are equal to those of $AB$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326944/evaluating-eigenvalues-of-a-product-of-two-positive-definite-matrices?rq=1

Comment: That post is correct. However, the largest eigenvalue of $AB$ is not necessarily $\|A\|\|B\|$.