# Maximal value of function under an invertible linear transformation is unchanged

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, maxima-minima

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966924/lower-bound-to-eigenvalues-of-a-product-of-two-positive-definite-matrices), it uses the property
\begin{align*}
\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{(A\sqrt{B}x,\sqrt{B}x)}{(\sqrt{B}x,\sqrt{B}x)}=
\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{(Ax,x)}{(x,x)}
\end{align*}
where $A,\sqrt{B}$ are invertible symmetric matrices and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I am thinking about how one would prove this. I provide a proof below using contradiction but language seems cumbersome to me. I am wondering whether a more concise proof is possible.

**Proof**

Suppose not. Then either
\begin{align*}
\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{(A\sqrt{B}x,\sqrt{B}x)}{(\sqrt{B}x,\sqrt{B}x)}<
\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{(Ax,x)}{(x,x)}
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{(A\sqrt{B}x,\sqrt{B}x)}{(\sqrt{B}x,\sqrt{B}x)}>
\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{(Ax,x)}{(x,x)}
\end{align*}
Let's just consider the first case as the other case would be similar.

Let $x_0=\arg \max_{x\neq 0}\frac{(Ax,x)}{(x,x)}$ and $x_1=\arg \max_{x\neq 0}\frac{(A\sqrt{B}x,\sqrt{B}x)}{(\sqrt{B}x,\sqrt{B}x)}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\frac{(A\sqrt{B}x_1,\sqrt{B}x_1)}{(\sqrt{B}x_1,\sqrt{B}x_1}< 
\frac{(A\sqrt{B}\sqrt{B}^{-1}x_0,\sqrt{B}\sqrt{B}^{-1}x_0)}{(\sqrt{B}\sqrt{B}^{-1}x_0,\sqrt{B}\sqrt{B}^{-1}x_0}=\frac{(Ax_0,x_0)}{(x_0,x_0)}
\end{align*}
This means $x_1\neq \arg \max_{x\neq 0}\frac{(A\sqrt{B}x,\sqrt{B}x)}{(\sqrt{B}x,\sqrt{B}x)}$ which gives us a contradiction.

Comment: Is $\sqrt{B}$ necessarily a matrix such that there is a matrix C s.t C^2 = B?

Comment: In the linkded question, yes. I am not sure whether that is needed in general.

Comment: Let $$f(x)={(Ax,x)\over (x,x)}$$ We have  $x\neq 0$ iff $y=\sqrt{B}x\neq 0$  and $x=\sqrt{B}^{-1}y.$ Thus $$\max_{x\neq 0}f(x)= \max_{\sqrt{B}x\neq 0}f(\sqrt{B}x) =\max_{x\neq 0}f(\sqrt{B}x)$$ The matrix. $A$ does need to be invertible.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\|\sqrt{B}x\|}\sqrt{B}x$ ranges over all unit vectors in the space. So, yes, the first equality in your post is an equality.