# Eigenvalues of a product of a symmetric and a diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let A be a symmetric matrix and B be a diagonal matrix with positive entries. Is there any way to prove that

> $\lambda_k(AB) \leq \lambda_k(A)\lambda_k(B)$,

where $\lambda_k(A)$ denotes the $k^{th}$ eigenvalue of A.

I've checked [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106191/eigenvalues-of-product-of-two-symmetric-matrices/106199#106199?s=8cea4bc63aa8424ea8c781b70547fcf2) but they bound the eigenvalues according to the weak majorization order. Also, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326944/evaluating-eigenvalues-of-a-product-of-two-positive-definite-matrices?noredirect=1&lq=1) shows a bound $\lambda_i(AB)\leq \lambda_i(A)\lambda_n(B)$, where $\lambda_i(A)$ denotes the ith eigenvalue of A, but it is only for positive definite matrices.